# c - array memory storage

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management

I am relatively new to C and am just learning about ways that memory is stored during a program. Can someone please explain why the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    float x[3][4];
    printf("%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n", &(x[0][0]), &(x[2][0]), &(x[2][4]), &(x[3][0]));
    return 0;
}
```

outputs this:

```
0x7fff5386fc40
0x7fff5386fc60
0x7fff5386fc70
0x7fff5386fc70
```

Why would the first 3 be different places in memory but the last be the same as the third?
Why is there a gap the size of 20 between the first two, but a gap the size of 10 between the second and third? The distance between &(x[2][0]) and &(x[2][4]) doesn't seem like half the distance between &(x[0][0])and &(x[2][0]).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare an array of size *n*, the indices range from 0 to *n* - 1. So `x[2][4]` and `x[3][0]` are actually stepping outside the bounds of your arrays.

If you weren't already aware, the multidimensional array you declared is actually an *array of arrays*.

Your compiler is laying out each array one after the other in memory. So, in memory, your elements are laid out in this order: `x[0][0]`, `x[0][1]`, `x[0][2]`, `x[0][3]`, `x[1][0]`, `x[1][1]`, and so on.

It looks like you already understand how pointers work, so I'll gloss over that. The reason the last two elements are the same is because `x[2][4]` is out of bounds, so it's referring to the next slot in memory after the end of the `x[2]` array. That would be the first element of the `x[3]` array, if there was one, which would be `x[3][0]`.

Now, since `x[3][0]` refers to an address that you don't have a variable mapping to, it's entirely possible that dereferencing it could cause a segmentation fault. In the context of your program, there just happens to be something stored at `0x7fff5386fc70`; in other words, you got lucky.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to pointer arithmetic.

Your array is *flat*, which means that data are stored in a linear way, each one after the other in memory. First `[0][0]` then `[0][1]`, etc.

The address of `[x][y]` is calculated as `(x*4+y)*float_size+starting_address`.

So the gap between the two first `[0][0]` and `[2][0]` is `8*float_size`. The difference is 20 in hexadecimal, which is 32 in decimal, `float_size` is then 4.

In between the second and third you have `(2*4+4)-(2*4)*float_size` which is 16 in decimal, so 10 in hexadecimal. This is exactly half the size of the previous because it is the size of one row (the size of 4 elements in the third row), and the previous is the size of two rows (the size of 8 elements in the first and second rows).

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are linear data structures. Irrespective of their dimension, say 1-dimensional or 2-dimensional or 3-dimensional, they are linearlly arranged.

Your  x[3][4] will be stored in memory as consecutive fixed sized cells like :

```
| (0,0) | (0, 1) | (0,2) | (0,3) | (1,0) | (1,1) | (1,2) | (1,3) | (2,0) | (2,1) | (2,2) | (2,3) |
```

This x[0][0] notation is matrix notation. On compile time, it is converted to pointer notation. The calculation is like:

```
x[i][j] = y * i + j  where y in your case is 4.
```

So on calculating by this way the outputs are perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Array elements in C are stored contiguously, in row-major order.   So, in your example,  `&x[row][column]` is exactly equal to `&x[0][0]+((row*4)+column))*sizeof(float)`   (when those addresses are converted to number of bytes, which is what you're outputting).

The third address you're printing has the second index out of bounds (valid values 0 to 3), and the fourth has the first index out of bounds (valid values 0 to 2).    It just happens that the values you've chosen work out to the same location in memory, because the rows are laid out in memory end-to-end.

There are 8 elements between `&(x[0][0])` and `&(x[2][0])`.   The actual difference in memory is multiplied by `sizeof(float)` which, for your compiler, is `4`.  `4*8` is `32` which, when printed as hex, is `0x20`, is the difference you're seeing.

If you picked a value of `row` and `column` where `((row*4)+column))` was `12(=3*4)` or more, your code would be computing the address of something outside the array.   Attempting to use such a pointer pointer (e.g. setting the value at that address) would give undefined behaviour.    You just got lucky that the indices you picked happen to be within the array.